# Pass data to Chart Js Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js, laravel-blade

I am importing my chart js code from

```
<script src="{{ asset('/css/tailwind/js/charts-bars.js') }}" defer></script>
```

I have some data from the controller and may I ask is it possible to pass the data to this script before the chart gets rendered?

My charts-bars.js code

```
const barConfig = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Active',
        backgroundColor: '#0694a2',
        // borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [-3, 14, 52, 74, 33, 90, 70],
      },
      {
        label: 'Not Active',
        backgroundColor: '#7e3af2',
        // borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [66, 33, 43, 12, 54, 62, 84],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
}

const barsCtx = document.getElementById('bars')
window.myBar = new Chart(barsCtx, barConfig)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First create one input hidden field in your blade template

```
<input type value="{{data}}" class="chartdata" >
```

then you can call like this

```
 datasets:$('.chartdata').val()
```

if you dont like to create input then you can use script in blade

```
<script>
var chartdata='{{data}}'
</script>
```

then in js file

```
 datasets:chartdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Data from the controller to blade.

Controller Code

```
    $dashboard_data = [
        'months' => $months,
    ];
    return view('admin.layouts.dashboard', compact('dashboard_data'));
```

get data directly in the blade and call chart function if data are available.

```
@section('scripts')
<script>
 <?PHP
   if (isset($dashboard_data['months']) && !empty($dashboard_data['months'])) {
  ?>

    var months = <?= $dashboard_data['months'] ?>;

 <?PHP  
 }
</script>
@endsection
```